# Point deviance calculation for deviance residuals

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model

I'm looking at [this post](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365799/deviance-residuals-in-poisson-glm) and the formula for the individual deviances (which have to be calculated before calculating the deviance residuals),

```
dev= 2*(counts*log(ifelse(counts==0,1,counts/fitted.values))-(counts-fitted.values))
```

changes counts of 0 in the data to 1 such that the first half of the equation (before the minus) becomes log(1)=0. My understanding is that this first half is the likelihood for the saturated model. I understand that the log of 0 will give $-\infty$ so it can't stay 0, but for what reason would a count of 0 give a likelihood of 0 in the saturated model?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You give a link to a previous post you are looking at, but the URL you give is broken.

Comment: @GordonSmyth whoops, I accidentally pasted the code in place of the link. Fixed

Comment: The first term is not the likelihood of the saturated model, so the premise of your question is incorrect. However if $\mu=0$ then the count also will be zero and $P(Y=0)=1$ so the log-likelihood will be $\log P(Y=0)=0$.